# Spring Websocket url hits RequestMapping but not MessageMapping

Tags: stomp, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I'm having trouble setting up a websocket configuration in an existing web application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/mobile");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/mobile-server");
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/mobile-user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/mobile-socket")
        .withSockJS()
        .setInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketInboxController{

    @MessageMapping("/inbox")
    @SendToUser("/mobile")
    public Map<String,Object> inbox(
    ){

        Map<String,Object> res = new HashMap<>();

        res.put("hello", "hello");

        return res;
    }
```

client

```
const webstomp = require('webstomp-client');

const socket = webstomp.client('ws://www.dev.server.com/mobile-socket',{
  debug:true
});

socket.connect('marc@gmail.com', '123456', (client) => {
  console.log('connected');

  socket.send("/mobile-server/inbox",)
  socket.subscribe("/mobile/inbox");
}, (client, err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

What I see when the client tries to connect is spring trying to match the /mobile-socket against the RequestMappings of the existing web application, finally hitting one that matches it by way of a @RequestMapping("/{somevar}").

I'm new to WebSockets, but I would expect the endpoint registration be a catchall for these kinds of connects?

Even after removing the erronous RequestMapping being hit, I can't seem to get the MessageMapping to be hit. I see this in my log

```
AntPathRequestMatcher.matches(150) | Request '/mobile-socket' matched by universal pattern '/**'
[MSA] DEBUG [2016-06-03T11:16:21,025] FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(219) | Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /mobile-socket; Attributes: [permitAll]
[MSA] DEBUG [2016-06-03T11:16:21,025] FilterSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired(348) | Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
[MSA] DEBUG [2016-06-03T11:16:21,025] AffirmativeBased.decide(66) | Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@444af45, returned: 1
[MSA] DEBUG [2016-06-03T11:16:21,025] FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(243) | Authorization successful
[MSA] DEBUG [2016-06-03T11:16:21,026] FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(256) | RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
[MSA] DEBUG [2016-06-03T11:16:21,026] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(325) | /mobile-socket at position 16 of 16 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
[MSA] DEBUG [2016-06-03T11:16:21,026] FilterChainProxy.doFilter(310) | /mobile-socket reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
[MSA] DEBUG [2016-06-03T11:16:21,027] ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(117) | Chain processed normally
[MSA] DEBUG [2016-06-03T11:16:21,027] HstsHeaderWriter.writeHeaders(130) | Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@53cc2afb
[MSA] DEBUG [2016-06-03T11:16:21,027] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(352) | SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
[MSA] DEBUG [2016-06-03T11:16:21,028] SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(120) | SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: I finally at least managed to remove the catchall RequestMapping from the by specifying RequestMapping(value="/{loc}", consumes="text/plain"), but now it is: Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'null' not supported :-(

Comment: After 2 days of going down the rabbit hole, I finally got a successful CONNECT after hacking nginx to send an Upgrade "WebSocket" Header against the endpoint/websocket url. Jeez this is ridiculously hard

Answer (score 1):

The Spring tries to match the `"/mobile-socket"` against the `RequestMappings` because all the requests go to `HandlerMapping` beans in the web application context to map incoming web requests to appropriate handlers. With the introduction of annotated controllers, `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` automatically looks for `@RequestMapping` annotations on all `@Controller` beans including the controller which has `@MessageMapping`.

Since the `@MessageMapping` can only be defined under `@Controller` annotation, Spring would try to match other `RequestMappings` as well.

One possible solution could be to introduce interceptor to handle the websocket request url to specifically map to a particular controller. You can give it a try!

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but as I understand it a more specific match would prevail over a non specific match. In this case a non specific RequestMapping match /{pathVar} is prevailing over a more specific MessageMapping one /inbox. I also cannot find the relevant mapping in the list of requestmappings that is being processed for a match. I would expect to see it there, which leads me to believe ComponentScanning is not hitting the MessageMapping annotation

Comment: I tried adding an additional ComponentScan for the Controller methods that contain the websocket Controllers. But Websocket maintains its own SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler but the AbstractHandlerMethodMapping that processes RequestHandlers runs first. I guess I have to find a way to either make the SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler run first or make sure the MessageMappings are registered with AbstractHandlerMethodMapping